# How to Copy List in Observable Collection in Thread

Tags: c#, list, data-binding, observablecollection

I have a background worker who fills/refills a List and After refilling and editing the List I copy this list in an Observable List:

```
this.OBSMailCountList = new ObservableCollection<IMailCount>(_allMailCounts);
```

The Problem is that the Collection is bind to an Live Diagramm and after the Copy in the List I get the

**Error**:

"The Value can not be NULL".

**My Question is:**

How to Copy an Observable Collection with Bindings in a Thread ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you have `_allMailCounts == null` at the moment you call observable collection constructor. You can check for `null` like this

```
if(_allMailCounts != null)
    OBSMailCountList = new ObservableCollection<IMailCount>(_allMailCounts);
```

Below is the answer on question "how to work with `ObservableCollection` from another tread":

---

Bind to observable collection defined as usual

```
ObservableCollection<IMailCount> _collection = new ObservableCollection<IMailCount>();
public ObservableCollection<IMailCount> Collection
{
    get { return _collection; }
    set
    {
        _collection = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

In another thread do work in this manner:

```
// create a copy as list in UI thread
List<IMailCount> collection = null;
Dispatcher.Invoke(() => collection = new List<IMailCount>(_collection));

// when finished working set property in UI thread
Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => Collection = new ObservableCollection<IMailCount>(collection));
```

Answer (score 1):

`Dispatcher.Invoke( Action )` will be used to make the call to the UI thread.

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
{
      // Set property or change UI compomponents.           
      OBSMailCountList = new ObservableCollection<IMailCount>(_allMailCounts);   
});
```